# CIImage: How to use CIAffineTransform?

Tags: cocoa, core-image

How can I make my `CIImage` finite after an `CIAffineTransform`, so i can pass it to `NSBitmapImageRep:initWithCIImage`?

Overall I want to overlay two images via CIAdditionCompositing. Because one image is smaller then the other, it want to position it first. I thought transforming the smaller image is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the crop filter.